# Solving $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{x^n}(\frac12)^x$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

For finding the $n$-th moment of $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
     2^{-x}& x \in \mathbb{N} \\ 
      0 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$ about $0$ , I need to solve $$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^x}$$ which I have no clue how it can be solved and where I should start. If it can't be solved for all $n$, is there any solutions for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$?

Comment: You can start off with the formula $\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} z^k$ for $|z| < 1$. Then keep applying $z\frac{d}{dz}$ to this (i.e differentiate with respect to $z$, then multiply by $z$. Then do this as many times as necessary for any *particular* value of $n$.).

Comment: I really don't know how should I do this,I'm so unfamiliar with calculus as I'm a cs student ,may you be more specific or apply this once that I can understand what should I do?

Comment: One example (for $n=1$): note that $\frac{d}{dz}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}z^k = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dz}\left(z^k\right)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} kz^{k-1}$ and $\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right) = \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$. So $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} kz^{k-1}= \frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$. Multiply both sides by $z$ now (and note you can drop the $k=0$ term from the sum since it equals $0$). Ultimately, you will substitute $z =1/2$ for your application.

Comment: It has no simple closed form, and is intimately related to Stirling partition numbers (a.k.a. Stirling numbers of the second kind) and the ordered Bell numbers, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number#Formula). For small $n$'s, the trick is as in the top comment. A slightly different approach is to decompose $k^n$ into the sum of falling factorials, such as $k^2 = k(k-1) + k$ and $k^3 = k(k-1)(k-2) + 3k(k-1) + k$ and then utilize the formula $$\frac{k!}{(1-z)^{k+1}}=\left(\frac{d}{dz}\right)^k\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)z^{n-k}.$$

Comment: I think I have the answer,actually I needed n=1,2 for finding variance but I was curious about higher moments that now I think it's more complicated but still solvable ,thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the definition of [polylogarithm functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm)$$\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}{x^n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x=\text{Li}_{-n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Starting at $n=0$, the first values are
$$\{1,2,6,26,150,1082,9366,94586,1091670,14174522,204495126\}$$ They correspond to sequence $A000629$ at $OEIS$ (have a look [here](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+2%2C+6%2C+26%2C+150%2C+1082%2C+9366%2C+94586%2C+1091670&sort=&language=&go=Search)).

A very good approximation is given by

$$\text{Li}_{-n}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\sim \frac{n!}{\left[\log(2)\right]^{n+1}}$$ (refering to  Benoit Cloitre's comment in the linked page).